# TCL Error: wrong # args: should be "proc name args body"

Tags: tcl

I wrote the following method in tcl:

```
proc read_csv ( csv_file) {

   package require csv
   package require struct::matrix

   struct::matrix m
   m add columns 8
   set f [open $csv_file]
   csv::read2matrix $f m {;}
   close $f

   return $m
}   


set m [read_csv "C:\\file.csv]
```

When I try to run it, I get the error:

wrong # args : should be "proc name args body"

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: This is not correct Tcl syntax. The parameter names must be enclosed in `{}`, not `()`. Also, the closing quotation marks are missing in the last line.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem

Comment: (Technically you could omit the `{}` in this case, but using them is never wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly that you are using `(`...`)` instead of `{`...`}`; Tcl doesn't use parentheses for enclosing formal parameters to procedures, but rather curly braces (the general "don't interpret this right now" syntax). Parentheses are only used usually for array variables and in expressions.